Why doesn't syslog's LOG_PERROR option cause the log priority to be printed?
The standard library for syslog allows you to specify the LOG_PERROR flag which causes syslog calls to additionally write the log message to stderr. I'm able to get it to print the message just fine, but it doesn't include the priority when it prints. For reference: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html
I have the following code:
#include <syslog.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    openlog("mytest", LOG_PERROR, LOG_DAEMON);
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "log 1");
    syslog(LOG_WARNING, "log 2");
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "log 3");
}

which when ran, produces the following output:
mytest: log 1
mytest: log 2
mytest: log 3

my question: Why isn't the log priority printed which each message? That is, why isn't it something like:
daemon.info mytest: log 1
daemon.warning mytest: log 2
daemon.error mytest: log 3

like it shows up in the system logs? Is there anyway to do this without making a separate call to print and without modifying the syslog library

That's just how it works. I believe putting the priority in the log file is done by syslogd, which is not involved when syslog() writes to stderr itself.
